# Angular 2 - Logout using ng2-idle

Tags: angular, logout, ng-idle

My problem is that when click on the logout button ng2-idle continues working.
And to try to solve this problem I set again the setIdle and setTimeout functions for 1 second.

However, when the user is transferred to the login screen, the app takes 1 second to give the timeout.

I like to know if have any way of forcing the timeout or end ng2-idle after click the logout button that call logout() function.

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {Router} from "@angular/router";
import {Http, Headers} from "@angular/http";
import {NgClass} from '@angular/common';
import {Observable} from "rxjs/Observable";
import 'rxjs/Rx';
import {HeaderService} from './header.service';
import {Idle, DEFAULT_INTERRUPTSOURCES} from 'ng2-idle/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-header',
    templateUrl: './js/app/header/header.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./js/app/header/header.component.css']
})

export class HeaderComponent {
    nome = localStorage['nome'];
    constructor(private _router: Router, private _http: Http, private _headerService: HeaderService, private idle: Idle) {
        idle.setIdle(5);
        idle.setTimeout(1800);
        idle.setInterrupts(DEFAULT_INTERRUPTSOURCES);

        idle.onTimeoutWarning.subscribe((countdown:number) => {
          console.log('TimeoutWarning: ' + countdown);
        });

        idle.onTimeout.subscribe(() => {
          console.log('Timeout');
          localStorage.clear();
          this._router.navigate(['/auth', {sessionExpirate: 'true'}]);
        });
        idle.watch();
    }

    logout() {
        this.idle.setIdle(1);
        this.idle.setTimeout(1);
        this.idle.setInterrupts(DEFAULT_INTERRUPTSOURCES);
        this._headerService.exit()
            .subscribe(
                data => {
                    this.idle.onTimeout.subscribe(() => {
                        console.log('Timeout');
                        localStorage.clear();
                        this._router.navigate(['/auth']);
                },
                error => console.log(error)
            )}
        )
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I got to work, follows the change in the logout() function:

```
logout() {
    this.idle.stop();
    this._headerService.exit()
        .subscribe(
            data => {
                localStorage.clear();
                this._router.navigate(['/auth']);         
            },
                error => console.log(error)
        )                          
    }
```

It is possible to use both function `this.idle.stop()` or `this.idle.ngOnDestroy();` [idle.ts](https://github.com/HackedByChinese/ng2-idle/blob/master/src/idle.ts)

The `this.idle.ngOnDestroy();` includes `this.idle.stop()` and `this.clearInterrupts();`

Comment: is ng2-idle still active project ? would you mind send me link

Comment: I believe that yes, and the sites are: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ng-idle/core have too https://github.com/HackedByChinese/ng2-idle