# Automatic logout in Angular 2 after few minutes

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular-services, angular2-directives

I want to implement a feature (in Angular2) i.e. After login, if a user keeps browser idle for 30 minutes, he should be logged out when coming back after 30 minutes. This has to be done by the front end only.

I am using angular CLI of Angular version 2.4

How can I implement this feature in my Angular2 application?

Comment: Have a look at `ng-idle` module https://github.com/HackedByChinese/ng-idle

Comment: @Justcode `ng-idle` is `angularjs` library, he is using `angular` in that case https://github.com/HackedByChinese/ng2-idle will do

Comment: `ng2-idle` check this npm package

Answer (score 11):

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { Router } from '@angular/router'
const MINUTES_UNITL_AUTO_LOGOUT = 60 // in mins
const CHECK_INTERVAL = 15000 // in ms
const STORE_KEY =  'lastAction';
@Injectable()
export class AutoLogoutService {
 public getLastAction() {
    return parseInt(localStorage.getItem(STORE_KEY));
  }
 public setLastAction(lastAction: number) {
    localStorage.setItem(STORE_KEY, lastAction.toString());
  }

  constructor(private router: Router) {
    this.check();
    this.initListener();
    this.initInterval();
    localStorage.setItem(STORE_KEY,Date.now().toString());
  }

  initListener() {
    document.body.addEventListener('click', () => this.reset());
    document.body.addEventListener('mouseover',()=> this.reset());
    document.body.addEventListener('mouseout',() => this.reset());
    document.body.addEventListener('keydown',() => this.reset());
    document.body.addEventListener('keyup',() => this.reset());
    document.body.addEventListener('keypress',() => this.reset());
  }

  reset() {
    this.setLastAction(Date.now());
  }

  initInterval() {
    setInterval(() => {
      this.check();
    }, CHECK_INTERVAL);
  }

  check() {
    const now = Date.now();
    const timeleft = this.getLastAction() + MINUTES_UNITL_AUTO_LOGOUT * 60 * 1000;
    const diff = timeleft - now;
    const isTimeout = diff < 0;

    if (isTimeout)  {
      localStorage.clear();
      this.router.navigate(['./login']);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I thought the code was useful, thank you. I just added a couple of things to it. I am calling the init routines explicitly as I found they were not called in the constructor at a suitable time. (not quite sure why). I also call a "destroy" method which removes the event listeners too. Finally in the check method I also check to see if they are currently logged in or not. I found otherwise that I was being forwarded to the login page from areas of my app where the user did not need to be logged in.

Comment: Glad it could help.You can make changes according to your requirement. There are several ways to do. Check could be done after initialization as well.

Comment: can you tell me, how to implement and use this? where should i add it in the module.ts and how does the the webpage react to it and auto logout? do i have to add it somehow in each controller or can i do this globally? thanks

Comment: Since its a service, provide it in your parent module like app-module. So,it will be available throughout your project. You have to update localstorage value on any page where you want to start the auto logout feature. In my case,it was after login page.

Comment: that seems very useful.....but can you tell me from where should I call this service, from app.component's ngoninit(), OR from somewhere else?

Comment: It works perfectly in web but not on mobile. Does anyone face the same issue... @NabinKumarKhatiwada do you aware of this mobile. Please let me know if you are

Comment: @Kartheeks It was working fine in mobile device as well when i was developing my project till angular 5. Currently, I am not working with angular projects so cannot help you. Very sorry.

Comment: @ronit you can call this service from anywhere you need to. You just need to inject in your root module once if you are working in single page app.

Answer (score 7):

I needed to do similar thing and created this: https://github.com/harunurhan/idlejs

It is not specifically for angular, but it is written in `typescript` so you get official typings.

It is simple and configurable without any dependencies. Some examples:

```
import { Idle } from 'idlejs/dist';

// with predefined events on `document`
const idle = new Idle()
  .whenNotInteractive()
  .within(60)
  .do(() => console.log('IDLE'))
  .start();
```

You can also use custom event targets and events:

```
const idle = new Idle()
  .whenNot([{
    events: ['click', 'hover'],
    target: buttonEl,
  },
  {
    events: ['click', 'input'],
    target: inputEl,
  },
  ])
  .within(10)
  .do(() => called = true)
  .start();
```

Comment: I hope you're still maintaining your repo 

Comment: I am.. it seems inactive because it was simply working for me without any issue and I didn't need an extra feature... If you have a feature request or found a bug, feel free to create an issue :)

Answer (score 3):

Basically what you need to do is to set a flag in case of any client activity and than after 30 minutes you have to check for that flag. If flag wasn't set which means user wasn't being active so you can perform a `logout()` action.

Here is some code sample(using [ngrx](https://github.com/ngrx/platform)) that you might find useful.

```
export class ClientActiveService {
  constructor(
    private store: Store<fromRoot.State>,
  ) { }

  run() {
    window.onload = () => { this.setActive(); };
    window.onmousemove = () => { this.setActive(); };
    window.onmousedown = () => { this.setActive(); }; 
    window.onclick = () => { this.setActive(); };
    window.onscroll = () => { this.setActive(); }; 
    window.onkeypress = () => { this.setActive(); };
  }

  setActive() {
     this.store.select(fromRoot.getClientActive)
     .take(1)
     .subscribe((active) => {
        if (!active) {
          this.store.dispatch(new layout.ClientActiveAction());
        }
      });
  }
}
```

`ClientActiveService` is a service that just emmiting an action if client was active. Somewhere like in `app.component.ts` you have to inject that service and call `this.clientActiveService.run();`

Then somewhere in your code you have to setup a 30 minutes timer where you subscribe for an `ClientInactiveAction` action

```
    setInterval(() => {
      this.store.select(fromRoot.getClientActive)
      .take(1)
      .subscribe((active) => {
        if (!active) {
          this.auth.logout();
        }
      });
    }, 30 * 60 * 1000);
```

> If you are not using [ngrx](https://github.com/ngrx/platform) you can just set a `variable/flag` instead in
>   `ClientActiveService` service. Then in  `setTimeout()` just check for
>   that variable and perform your `logout()` action

Otherwise you might wanna use [ng2-idle](https://github.com/HackedByChinese/ng2-idle) library. In that case [Angular 2 - Logout using ng2-idle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39192832/angular-2-logout-using-ng2-idle) might help.

Comment: i am creating ClientActiveService, but its showing an error in the constructor of this class: 'cannot find nameSpace fromRoot'

Comment: @ErVipinSharma if you are not using `ngrx` just take out the `private store: Store<fromRoot.State>` and all related code that belongs to it

Comment: `import * as fromRoot from '@ngrx/store';` not seams to be right. You should import from your `reducers` something like `import * as fromRoot from '../reducers';` just put the  right path.

Comment: you are defining your own reducers in your app, check the `ngrx` guide https://gist.github.com/btroncone/a6e4347326749f938510 and https://github.com/ngrx/platform/tree/master/example-app form more details

Comment: window onclick and window onscroll did not work for me. document onclick is working better.